# Unable to update Lumia 620 to Cyan Update India

Tags: nokia-lumia-620

I am unable to update my Lumia 620 to the latest Lumia Cyan update.

Although the Nokia support site says that the release is available in India for the Lumia 620, no notification has popped yet for me.

Furthermore, when I try to look for updates manually by going to **Settings** > **Phone Updates** > **Check for updates**, it shows *Your phone is up to date*.

Comment: What OS version do you currently have installed? If you've updated to the 8.1 Developer Preview, you'll either have to wait for an additional fix for a BitLocker issue, or roll back to 8.0.

Comment: I am currently on Lumia Black,I never installed Developer Preview

Comment: When you go to **settings** -> **about**, what does it show underneath the Model, above the [ **more information** ] button?

Comment: It Shows following four fields:Name,Model,Software,Screen Resolution .And for the Software it  is showing  as Windows Phone 8.0

Comment: Do you have a data plan? By that, can you get to other items online from this phone?

Comment: It would normally also show a field to indicate which country variant it is, or carrier variant; If your phone happened to be a grey import, it mightn't be ready for the update (For example, [Nepalese models aren't ready yet](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/wp8-availability-in-asia-pacific/))

Comment: Rowland ,it does not show any country variant field,but i purchased it from India with all the legal documents.When i first purchased ,it was on Lumia Amber,i was able to update it to Lumia Black easily  by OTA update using Wi-Fi, when the release happened here about 4 months back.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **you'll have to wait a bit longer**.

Even if you bought a phone in India, the phone may not report itself as an "Indian" Lumia 620. There are many different versions of the software for each part of the world.

For example, I live in Ireland but the Lumia devices I own run German, UK and U.S. software versions. That means the release schedule for Ireland does not apply to my devices.

If you don't want to wait for the proper release of Cyna + 8.1, you could always [join the Dev Preview programme](http://www.wpcentral.com/how-sign-windows-phone-81-preview-developers).